# How do I make higher enchants on my weapons, tools, and armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been looking around trying to find a way to make my enchants higher on my weapons, tools, and armor. I know it's possible in vanilla Minecraft, but haven't found anything. Can someone please give me a pre-written command for a good set of tools, weapons, and armor? However, please don't make it too overpowered, and use enchantments useful to the item except for silk touch.

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10606/are-questions-regarding-minecrafts-commands-and-syntax-eligible-for-flagging We discourage "questions" that are "asking people to make minecraft commands for them".

Comment: Questions that ask people to make a command for them are strictly disallowed here, as they mainly help nobody but the asker. The whole point of this site is to have posts that can help everyone.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean maximum legal enchantment levels, such as Sharpness 5, Protection 4, Fire Aspect 2, etc., you can do that with an anvil using the item you want to enchant and an enchanted book obtained in Creative Mode (all enchanted books in creative are max level).

You can also use [`/enchant <player> <enchantment ID> [level]`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#enchant)  where `<player>` would be yourself, `<enchantment ID>` would be the numerical ID of the enchantment, and `[level]` would be the maximum level of that enchantment. This command applies the specified enchantment to the item in your hand. You can find a list of numerical IDs and levels [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantment#Enchantments).

However, if you're hoping for enchantment levels higher than the maximum legal ones, such as Sharpness 2000 or Protection 10000, you'll need an NBT editor such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) to change the enchantment level through the world data. You can also use Essentials on a server, but that solution leaves the vanilla scope and is less efficient for a simple enchanting task.

Comment: basically what i'm asking for is a command that will make the enchantment levels higher so for example I can have a sword with sharpness X

Comment: @user120715 To use a command, you'll need to install a server and install the Essentials plugin, then in the config.yml file, find `unsafe-enchantments` and change it to `true`. After that, you can use /enchant with higher levels. I don't believe there's any other way than that.

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking for something like a sword named "SuperSaber" with Sharpness X or something absurd like a wooden shovel with Luring VII, then you have 2 choices.

If you'd like to use my pre-written commands:

```
/give @p iron_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:10}]}
```

This command will give you an iron sword with Sharpness X.

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:21,lvl:8}]}
```

This is a diamond sword with Looting VIII.

Or if you are feeling good, download the [TooManyItems](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1272385-toomanyitems-the-inventory-editor-and-more-1-8) mod.

Comment: Do you think you could explain in detail how your commands work, and **clean up your post!** (ex: Instead of using the `/enchant` command, you can try using the NBT options within the `/give` command, which has more flexibility and does not have the enchantment level restrictions.)